# Xrm.Page.getControl() not working in Dynamics 365 Sales Hub

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci

`Xrm.Page.getControl("webResource1").getObject()` is working fine in Sales Dynamics 365, while it's not working in Sales Hub.

The counterpart is to use `formContext`, but how to call a script in a web resource from another web resource.

Eg. 
`Xrm.Page.getControl("webResource1").getObject().contentWindow.function1()` is working fine in Sales, but not in Unified UI.

Answer (score 4):

**`Xrm.Page` has been deprecated** (Deprecated methods are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/get-started/whats-new/customer-engagement/important-changes-coming#some-client-apis-are-deprecated))

You now have to do the following:

- When you register your event you **must** tick the `Pass Execution Context as first parameter` checkbox
- In your function you have to add a new parameter called `executionContext` (the name doesn't really matter)

When you've done the above, you can access the new `formContext` object which contains most of the methods included in `Xrm.Page`

More information on `formContext` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/clientapi-form-context)

For example:

```
function myHandler(executionContext) 
{
  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
  var myWebResource = formContext.getControl("webResource1");
}
```

---

**Edit to address null `getObject` error**

The object returned from `getControl()` does have a `getObject` method ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/controls/getobject)) which states it will return either:

> - An IFRAME returns the IFrame element from the Document Object Model (DOM).
> - A Silverlight web resource will return the Object element from the DOM that represents the embedded Silverlight plug-in.

If you're getting a null object then you've probably got an error with the name of your webresource.

Open your CRM form in designer mode and and locate your webresource. Double-click to view its properties. You're looking for the `field name` which in CRM Online is prefixed with "WebResource_"

For example:

[image]

Comment: Agreed. Tried this one as well, but how do I get the web contents of this web resource?

formContext.getControl("webResource1") does not have any getObject function, or it aklways returns null

Comment: `getObject` does exist (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/controls/getobject) so you must have the name of your webresource wrong. See my edit

Answer (score 1):

There’s another design change causing this `null` when using `formContext.getControl("WebResourceName").getObject()` because Sales hub or UCI form tab having web resource is not rendered yet unless it’s clicked/navigated.

Similar topic in [Dynamics community thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/306022/xrm-page-getcontrol-webresource-getobject-contentwindow-document-error-in-unified-interface/945988)

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerapps-docs/issues/554)